# about model training results from Spark Scala ML API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pipeline

I'm new to the **spark scala** ML package.

After assembling a pipeline and fit some regression model to training dataset (using the command: `val model = pipeline.fit(training)`), how can I check/print out the fitted model details: *coefficients*, *statistics*, *R2* , etc?

Something like the "`summary(model)`" in R language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, get the appropriate stage and then  view its contents:

```
val pipelineModel: PipelineModel = pipelineData.fit(data)
val transformedColumns = pipelineModel.stages
val lda = transformedColumns(9).asInstanceOf[LDAModel]
// 9 is the index of the stage in the pipeline. If you just have a single stage, it would be zero then
```

In above case, once you have the `LDAModel`, you can now view the statistics.

`LDAModel` is just an example. Lets say if your pipeline stage is `CountVectorizer`, then use `CountVectorizerModel`. If you use `IDF`, then use `IDFModel`.

Comment: May I ask what is the "LDAModel"? 
If I use "LDAModel" literally, I got the following error msg:
command-1400048289403228:2: error: not found: type LDAModel

Comment: Hi. LDAModel is just an example. It depends on on your model. If your pipeline used `Count Vectorizer`, your model would be `CounterVectorizerModel`